# Analyzing importance of continuous and categorical variables in linear regression in R

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, predictive-models, continuous-data

I am using R. I have a data set with a binary (0,1) response and both continuous and categorical predictors. I would like to test the overall importance of these predictors one by one, and I am looking for suggestions on how to do this. I am not trying to select an overall model yet. I am just trying to see which variables are individually significantly associated to the response.

Here is an example concerning categorical variables ... Let's call the response "y". Let's say my categorical predictor is called "xCat" and has levels A, B, C, and D. I would like to test if xCat has a statistically significant association with y. I want to test for overall significance, not just significant differences from a single reference group. Here is what I have tried so far ...

Option A using LRT:

```
fitCat <- glm(y~xCat, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)
fit0 <- glm(y~1, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)
anova(fit0, fitCat, test="LRT")
```

Option B using drop1:

```
fitCat <- glm(y~xCat, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)
drop1(fitCat, .~., test = "Chisq")
```

I would then look at p-values for either of these outputs. If the p-value is >0.05, then I would say there is not significant association. Is this actually testing what I think it is testing? I am concerned about violating assumptions of normality and equal variance for the ANOVA. Any comments or suggestions?

Here is an example of the continuous predictors... Let's call the continuous predictor "xCon". Here is what I've tried ...

```
fitCon <- glm(y~xCon, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)
summary(fitCon)
```

I would then look at the p-value from the output. If the p-value is >0.05, then I would say there is not significant association. Is there anything I'm missing here? assumptions I need to check or common pitfalls?

Let me know if you have suggestions!

Edit: I will eventually be creating a predictive model. However, I am currently focused on exploratory data analysis.

Comment: "Importance" is a poorly defined concept, but p-values are definitely not a good way to quantify it. See our [tag:importance] tag for more about this topic.

Comment: I wish I could be more specific when defining importance, but I'm not sure I know the right words. I am mainly interested in eventually creating a model for predictions. But right now I am trying to weed out variables that don't seem to be connected to the outcome. What would you suggest if not p-values?

Comment: The fact that your goal is to build a predictive model is important context. Please edit that information into the question.

Comment: I have added the edit!

Comment: Weeding out apparently unimportant variables is stepwise regression which is a terrible idea, especially if you want to be well calibration and have correct standard errors.  And you are using an $\alpha$ cutoff that is too small for this purpose (little damage is done by using $p < 0.5$ unlike the selection bias caused by $p < 0.05$).  And binary logistic models do not assume normality.  For your purpose I would use pseudo $R^2$; see for example [this](https://hbiostat.org/bib/r2.html) which are computed by the R `rms` package `lrm` function.  You can extend them to partial $R^2$;

Comment: "Testing variables one by one" is not the way to achieve your objective of obtaining good prediction.  For better approaches, please search our site for threads about the Lasso, glmnet, random forests, model identification, cross-validation, and overfitting.

Comment: Important information to add to your query concerns the sheer *number* of features being evaluated. If it's a large number, e.g., hundreds or more, then eliminating features with *no* relationship with the response could be a useful first step before employing one of the machine learning algorithms mentioned by whuber. How this is best done is the question. Opposition to stepwise regression is ubiquitous on this site but Bob Stine, Wharton statistician, makes the case for it particularly wrt large data. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a predictive model, evaluating variables one at a time is a very bad approach. For multiple reasons, one of them being that this completely ignores the covariance between the predictors.

Instead, consider using a model with all predictors and some [regularization](/questions/tagged/regularization). The LASSO or elastic net are common ways to do this.

Another way to go about this is to use a machine learning model (again, with all predictors). Perhaps the simplest way to do this is to use a [random-forest](/questions/tagged/random-forest), because it requires less 'tuning' than almost any other machine learning method.